# Data is not being inserted into Database

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to insert this data into my table and, for some reason, it is not being inserted and I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this.

Controller:

```
    public function insert_comments()
{
    $userID = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data['user_id'] = $this->Review_Model->getUserID($userID);
    $data['review_id'] = get_cookie('ReviewID');
    $data['comments'] = $this->input->post('comments');

    //using the function in the model insert the comments,reviewID,userID
    $this->Review_Model->insert_comments($data);

}
```

Model:

```
public function insert_comments($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('comments',$data);

    }

function getUserID($username)
{
    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('username = ' . $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

Table:

[image: Table]

Comment: Did you connect to the database ?

Comment: yh i have connected the database in database.php , i have managed to insert the data when the user register for the first time so i tried to use the same method but for some reason it is not working for the comments. so when i press post comment on the website it and check the database nothing appears in the database

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion

Connecting to the database (if you forgotten)

```
class Review_Model extends CI_Model {
   public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->database();
   }
```

In your code, `getUserID` function returns a result object. Not `user_id` value. So, You should make following changes.

```
function getUserID($username)
{
    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result()->user_id;
}
```

Now it will return `user_id` , not the object.

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: i'm trying to get to use the username to get the id of the user and i have managed to get the review_id and the comments but for some reason when i pass it into the function the variables it is not inserting the values

Comment: i want to get the user_id,review_id,the comments and store it in the database so i can do a query to get the comments and the user_id and display it on the page so that when the page is refreshed it will still show the comments like the game website IGN